# Subset pandas groupby index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-indexed dataframe called `ndf_2` Pandas

```
                 ip_collection_2 ip_offset_2
user_nm   month             
100118231   2   set([142.136])  set([])                         
100118231   3   set([142.136])  set([142.136])           
100118231   6   set([108.0])    set([142.136])              
100118231   7   set([108.0])    set([108.0])               
100118231   8   set([142.136])  set([108.0])
```

for months 1-6 and 6-12, I would like to find the union of `ip_collection_2` and `ip_offset_2`.  First thing I do is make a groupby object:

```
groupwork=ndf_2.groupby(level=[0,1])
```

Now how can I subset by my month index?

I know this is in the docs somewhere, but there is something I am clearly not getting, as I just spent 45 minutes there and am now on SO.  A simple demonstration/perception adjustment would be much, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to group by bins

```
df = df.reset_index(level=1)
groups = df.groupby(df.month.replace(range(1,13),["1-6"]*6+["7-12"]*6))
```

Above is a little ugly but semantically it groups replaces 1-6 with a value "1-6" and the same with 7-12 values. Then groups by those bins.

```
getUnions = lambda df: df[df['ip_collection_2'].isin(df['ip_offset_2'])]['ip_collection_2'].values
unions = groups.apply(getUnions)
```

next you just apply a lambda function that finds the union between columns.  Had trouble finding a quick method for the union but this works

```
print unions
```

**output**

```
month
1-6      [set([142.136]), set([142.136])]
7-12                       [set([108.0])]
dtype: object
```